# How to pass Oozie configuration to workflow actions, such as Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

How can one pass Oozie configuration values to workflow actions?

For instance, Oozie is aware of the job tracker URL:

```
# oozie admin -oozie localhost:10000 -configuration | fgrep tracker
oozie.actions.default.job-tracker : server1:8080
```

Now in workflow.xml, we find:

```
<action name="hive-5228" cred="hcat">
    <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        [... deleted parameters for clarity ...]
    </hive>
    <ok to="hive-38fe"/>
    <error to="email-c6f0"/>
</action>
```

Currently, ${jobTracker} is hardcoded in a Java properties file, duplicating the information since Oozie is already aware of the job tracker URL.  Is it possible to reference the Oozie configuration from within the worklow.xml file?  I tried the following to no vail:

```
<job-tracker>${oozie.actions.default.job-tracker}</job-tracker>
```

This returns an error stating that variable 'oozie' is not defined.

I want to avoid creating specific property files for DEV, QA and PROD and since Oozie already knows the specific configuration for the environment, I would like it to pass the data to the coordinators and workflows.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access the variable data using  `<job-tracker>${wf:conf('oozie.actions.default.job-tracker')}</job-tracker>`

Comment: I tried it and it does not work.  Using Oozie 4.1.0-cdh5.5.2.

Comment: as per https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.1_Workflow_Job_Properties_or_Parameters, It looks like you cannot access properties that are *NOT* in the format of a java identifier directly, but use wf:conf(property) to access that. I am not sure why the variable that you are reading is not accessible. May be you can try with accessing `wf:conf{'job-tracker' }` instead ? skipping the `oozie.actions.default`

Comment: I tried `${wf:conf{'job-tracker' }}` and it failed too.  Looks like `${wf:conf()}` only works for values passed as parameters when starting the job, i.e. with the -D flag or maybe with the properties files provided.  Oozie configuration does not seam to be available for workflows.

Comment: Same behavior here. I get the error 'Expression language evaluation error, Validation error :No function is mapped to the name "wf:conf"'

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to define the **name-node** and **job-tracker** in every and each of your workflows, you only have to add the following properties in the Oozie service configuration (**oozie-site**):

```
oozie.actions.default.name-node=<name-node-value>
oozie.actions.default.job-tracker=<job-tracker-value>
```

It worked for me using **Oozie 4.2.0**.